# Hook into WooCommerce product file upload and run script

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to run a PHP script whenever I upload a purchasable download file to a WooCommerce product (if it helps, the script automatically generates a 30 second sample file from an mp3 and adds it to the Media Library). Is there a WooCommerce action hook I can use for this? I'd prefer not to have to use a cron job if possible.

I'm hoping for something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_upload_product_file', 'create_sample_mp3' );
// no idea what the real action hook name might be
function create_sample_mp3($file){
    // generate 30 second clip of $file and add to media library
}
```